# how do I configure dhclient for comcast /64 prefix?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

I did have everything working, but when I updated my router to a supported version of ubuntu, it broke (Ubuntu 14.4)

Where things go wrong is dhclient never grabs a /64.  It either gabs the IP for my external interface or it tries to gab the /64 on the internal interface.

I think the problem is in /etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf

```
interface "eth2" {
send dhcp6.ia-pd 1;
script "/etc/dhclient-exit-hooks";
}
```

eth2 is my external interface, I have my exit hooks set to config eth0.  I do have NetworkManager mange set to true

If I run

```
dhclient -6 -P eth2
```

it gives me my prefix, but it doesn't add the address to eth0

Comment: Please edit your question heading to express an actual question.

Comment: If you are running `dhclient` on eth2, why would you expect it to do anything with eth0?

Comment: eth0 is set by the exit hook.  That will run some code to add an address to eth0 there is no dhcp server on eth2 for IPv6 prefix, only comcast can hand me my prefix.